# Alter a custom Listview

Tags: android, listview

I currently have a ListView that takes in an array of strings. It is created in the following way (in the onCreate() method):

```
     private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

     String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ingredients_array);
     lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.itemList1);
     adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_view_format2,R.id.list_content2,list);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

R.layout.list_view_format2: a custom ListView format. It contains an ImageView and a TextView
R.id.list_content2: Id of the Text View within R.id.list_view_format2

I want to access each child of ListView dynamically and compare the text(TextView) with a string. Later, I would like to modify the image(ImageView) associated with the child based on the search. Could you please help me with this? I have searched around a lot but I haven't been able to find any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understood you need to custom the listview, in order to do this you need to create your own [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html), there are plenty of [example](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right.I need a custom Adapter. I was able to figure it out myself in the meanwhile. I have edited your post to include my solution. This link helped me: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-convertview-in-getview-to-make.html

Comment: @Abhijit - It would be more appropriate to post your code as a new answer or include it in your original question.